# Adding a new Meteor CollectionFS store

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, meteor, graphicsmagick

I've been using **CollectionFS** with GraphicsMagick to crop and store images in **S3**. I realized that the images are too big for mobile and now I want to store scaled down versions. Here's what I've tried.

```js
images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [
    new Store("images", imageOptions),
    new Store("thumbs", thumbOptions) // added later
  ]
});
```

The `thumbs` store works for new images but the startup function to scale down the old ones doesn't.

```js
Meteor.startup(function () {
  images.find().forEach(function (fileObj) {
    if (!fileObj.copies.thumbs) {
      var readStream = fileObj.createReadStream('images');
      var writeStream = fileObj.createWriteStream('thumbs');
      gm(readStream)
        .scale(THUMB_DIM, THUMB_DIM)
        .stream()
        .pipe(writeStream);
    }
  });
});
```

Any ideas? Could it be caused by the `readstream` coming from **S3**?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you are missing the second parameter in the gm command, which should be the original file name. We used the following migration script to create copies of our images in a new store:

```
Migrations.add({
    version: 2,
    name: 'Save old images to new image stores',
    up: function() {
        console.log('Save old images to new image stores');
        Images.find().fetch().forEach(function(image) {
            if (image.copies['32x32'].size === 0) {
                console.log('creating 32x32 image: ' + image.name());
                var readStream = image.createReadStream('original');
                var writeStream = image.createWriteStream('32x32');
                try {
                  gm(readStream, image.name()).resize(32, 32).stream().pipe(writeStream);
                }
                catch (e) {
                  console.log(e);
                }
            }
            if (image.copies['80x80'].size === 0) {
                console.log('creating 80x80 image: ' + image.name());
                var readStream = image.createReadStream('original');
                var writeStream = image.createWriteStream('80x80');
                try {
                  gm(readStream, image.name()).resize(80, 80).stream().pipe(writeStream);
                }
                catch (e) {
                  console.log(e);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    down: function() {
    }
});
```